# Groovy: Apply ToString transform to all classes in the package

Tags: grails, groovy, transform, aspectj, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a Grails 2.3.7 application. All Command Objects(parameters to controller actions) are stored in a single package. I want to apply `groovy.transform.ToString` to all classes in this package, to avoid putting `@ToString(includeNames=true)` on every class. Further purpose is to create an aspect to log all controller actions, including implicit params object and command object.

Is that possible? How can i achieve that? Should I apply the AST transformation(`org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ToStringASTTransformation`) directly to classes found using reflection at application startup? Or should I dynamically add `ToString` annotation to metaclass during classloading / aplication startup?

Comment: Applying using reflection, or metalss stuff wont work.. AST is for compiletime. Your option is to write a custom AST transformation

Comment: The transformation I want to apply already exists - org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ToStringASTTransformation. The problem is how to mark all classes in a package for compiler to apply it without excplicitly putting annotation for each class. Or possibly you mean something else by "writing custom AST transformation"?

Comment: Compilation customizers http://groovy-lang.org/dsls.html#compilation-customizers could possibly be a solution

Comment: If you were using Grails 3 I could help you